# How to shrink string which exceeds width of the screen

Tags: react-native

[image]

As you see on the screen, the content (`New Cateogry fromStylepost`) exceeds the normal width of the screen and break the grid style.

How can I set every exceeding string to '...'?

For example I want to convert them `New Cateogry fromStylepost` from to `New Category fro...`

I'm using FlatList and this is renderItem function

```
return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={...}>
    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      {this._renderImage(item)}
      <RkText rkType="primary3">{item.name}</RkText> //I need to style this!
      <RkText rkType="secondary2 hintColor">{item.length} Style</RkText>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numberOfLines` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#numberoflines
And `ellipSizeMode` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#ellipsizemode

Example:

`<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>my text is very very very very very long<Text>`

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'letterSpacing' but works only in iOS

for details
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

Answer (score 1):

Each font has a font-contant and a font size (in pixels).

Number of possible characters can be calculated like:

NunberOfCharPerLine= WidthInPixel*FontConstant/FontSize

So if font constant (set by the font family) is set to 1.9, your control width is 100 pixels and you choose font size 18px, Number of displayed characters in a line is:

100*1.9/18 which is 10.5 (so about 10 characters).

Some example to font constants:

```
American Typewriter = 2.14

Baskerville = 2.14

Georgia = 1.91

Times New Roman = 2.21

Arial = 1.91

Calibri = 2.1

Helvetica Neue = 1.9

Lucida Grande = 1.91

Tahoma = 1.91

Trebuchet MS = 2.11

Verdana = 1.73

Courier New = 1.64
```

Comment: Nice Low level implementation. :)